# Why am I getting "NaN" here?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to make a simple calculator, however, when I try to add two numbers, I'm getting the `NaN` result.

Before this problem, the function `sumar()` was returning `[object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement]`, however after adding `+` when calling the dom, it returns `NaN`.

**HTML File**

```
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label for="op1">Ingrese un numero</label>
            <input type="number" value="0" id="op1"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="op2">Ingrese otro numero</label>
            <input type="number" value="0" id="op2"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="resultado">0</div>
    <button onclick="sumar()">Sumar</button>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**JS file**

```
const sumar = ()=> {
    const op1 = +document.getElementById("op1");
    const op2 = +document.getElementById("op2");
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = op1 + op2;
}
```

Comment: You're getting the elements but not the `.value` properties of the elements.

Comment: Also be careful that `.value` always is a string, so you have to explicitly make them numbers before adding.

Comment: @Pointy Yep. He already converted the string to integer by using the '+' operator in JavaScript.

Comment: @iTzVoko well had the `.value` part been there after `getElementById()` then yea

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the value of the elements

```
const sumar = ()=> {
    const op1 = +document.getElementById("op1").value;
    const op2 = +document.getElementById("op2").value;
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = op1 + op2;
}
```

And `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to remove the error

```
const sumar = ()=> {
    const op1 = +document.getElementById("op1").value;
    const op2 = +document.getElementById("op2").value;
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = parseFloat(op1) + parseFloat(op2);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was it. Thank you for your help and hope you have a great day.

Comment: He already converted the input value to an integer using the '+' operator in JavaScript; so there's no need for `parseInt` or `parseFloat` parsing functions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not receiving string values . try using

```
  parseInt(op1)+parseInt(op2)
```

Comment: Looks good too, but the other answer had more explanation. Thanks for trying :)

Comment: He's already converted the input to an integer, by using the '+' sign in JavaScript. `+'24'` is `24` integer.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript file, try to replace your code with this

```
const sumar = () => {
   const op1 = document.getElementById("op1").value
   const op2 = document.getElementById("op2").value
   document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = parseInt(op1) + 
   parseInt(op2)
}
```

i've try in playcode.io, and that's work well.